How to add nested classes in C#
How can I add the name and value components with the desired data in the Subset class, Subjectlist, when I am adding data in the ActualFrame class?
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace SP2_Admin.Models
{
    public class Rootobject
    {
        public Actualframe[] ActualFrame { get; set; }
    }

    public class Actualframe
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string hashcode { get; set; }
        public string start { get; set; }
        public string end { get; set; }
        public string Duration { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public Subjectlist[] SubjectList { get; set; }
    }

    public class Subjectlist
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }
}


C# :

Actualframe act = new Actualframe();

     act.id = 0;
     act.hashcode = "jhhjh";
     act.Duration = "10";
     act.start = "1";
     act.end = "0";
     act.Type = "t";      

act.Subjectlist = ??????????;


how i can set data in act.Subjectlist

do you know the size of the subject list in forehand?

If you do not know the size of SubjectList beforehand, then maybe change its type to List<SubjectList>
